# Facebook API return a list of object ID's

Tags: python, facebook, social-networking

I am trying to get a list of ids from the most recent posts on my profile so I can perform operations on each post individually elsewhere but am having issues isolating the ids from the rest of the post data. It says that the posts object is a dictionary but when I try to iterate through it using posts['id'] I only get back myID, and when I use for p in posts posts[p] I get back everything. I am relatively new to python and am having some major issues, how can I get a list of just the ids?

```
import facebook
import json

token = {'****'}
graph = facebook.GraphAPI(token)
page_ids = []
myID = graph.request('/me?fields=id')
print(myID['id'])
posts = graph.get_object(id=myID['id'],fields='posts.fields(object_id)')
print(posts)



{'object_id': '503243983830603', 'id': '2894021623958853_2890876384273377'}, {'object_id': '402662493728056', 'id': '2894021623958853_2890866360941046'}, {'id': '2894021623958853_2890842810943401'}], 'paging': {'previous': 'https://graph.facebook.com/v4.0/2894021623958853/posts?fields=object_id&since=1569687697&access_token=EAAKsaVifZCCYBAE7ofO8qRSheQsBhi2mYrZB39wzfhCZAJ2ejGoyZAi8hdKZAoEjIWUEk7Y1Y8nCb9yrU17JEXf2jGMF7E4SVpneE3EYbCV2zDRb1K8ZCkcY5tQP00DALPWYXNLimGxyGsugwK5GPOZC19suEItAszJM4RHFaTUMMZBXiyiHH0mnzpdUP0vl2MklfCct4mk6EwZDZD&limit=25&__paging_token=enc_AdCi4Pnb01TJi24NGPgqiXLRi3AuoPtBkgJfx43aXRQwPPzkfcJ0BHQuqNXebzs5Vm01uEHcSrvAtTiYcTKvJu5raYCKn4pftMqeyD60hDz0PgZDZD&__previous=1', 'next': 'https://graph.facebook.com/v4.0/2894021623958853/posts?fields=object_id&access_token=EAAKsaVifZCCYBAE7ofO8qRSheQsBhi2mYrZB39wzfhCZAJ2ejGoyZAi8hdKZAoEjIWUEk7Y1Y8nCb9yrU17JEXf2jGMF7E4SVpneE3EYbCV2zDRb1K8ZCkcY5tQP00DALPWYXNLimGxyGsugwK5GPOZC19suEItAszJM4RHFaTUMMZBXiyiHH0mnzpdUP0vl2MklfCct4mk6EwZDZD&limit=25&until=1569590626&__paging_token=enc_AdDfKEIsYp9uDTOhVdXvJ2KKarEfKqyiV3stKSk3ZBPh5rNWDDihjnBZC29jw2xQF1fmjViUe18SIlW8CW4CVV5sFsEtxdSFOnQZA63RNgWrk4ZAqQZDZD'}}, 'id': '2894021623958853'}
```